# Windows outgoing port forwarding

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, port

The client program on Windows 10 wants to connect the server through port 445.

The client program does not have setting to change outgoing port.

For some reason the remote port 445 is not available (ISP locks it) so 1445 is open instead.

Is there a way to forward outgoing traffic on Windows 10 from one port to another? If not which 3rd party software is available for it?

Haven't found outgoing port forwarding settings on my router, maybe there's software for it for Windows?

Scheme:

[Net scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk0mz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Port 445 per default is used for Microsoft Active Directory Services and SMB file shares. (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers))

Whatever you do, those are NOT SAFE to route through an open internet connection and no server should publish these services. That is why the ISP might be blocking the requests.

Best solution if you want to access SMB shares on a server over the internet would be to create a VPN connection to that server (but that has to be enabled on the server side as well).

Btw. who ever runs the server should definitely NOT publish SMB or AD protocols on the internet or he might find himself in a world of pain soon afterwards.

Comment: Yes. Exactly I want to get access to my folders via SMB.
Thank you for warning about security.
I'm OK with username and password on it.
But your post doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Then the best way would be to create an encrypted VPN connection between server and client. That way you can safely use SMB in your virtual private network without having to worry about the SMB protocol security issues.

Comment: OK maybe in this case — yes. But the question was about outgoing port forwarding whatever the reason is. And also there's no justification for ISP locking port (unless he has option to unlock it). It is like postmen in post office would decide if they want to deliver a letter or to keep it.

Comment: You cannot change the port on the outgoing side once the packets have left your network. You can only set up a port forwarding rule on the incoming side. However, you should definitely not do that in this case - and the ISP blocks these port for good reason actually, to protect their customers.

Comment: But you can change the port on the outgoing side _before_ the packets leave your network, as long as the receiver's network changes it back... But really, use a VPN.